# How to get link before 1st backslash with http PHP

Tags: php, html, url

I have a link like below:

```
$link = http://mytour.com:8080/en/admin/dashboard//tmp/Rc4Lw3
```

How can i get it to be like the one below in PHP:

```
$link = http://mytour.com:8080
```

Sorry if this is a newbie question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [parse_url($link)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

   ```
   $link = 'http://mytour.com:8080/en/admin/dashboard//tmp/Rc4Lw3';
   $parsed_link = parse_url($link);
   echo $parsed_link['scheme']."//".$parsed_link['host'].":".$parsed_link['port'];
   ```
2. preg_match() - worse

   ```
   preg_match("/^http[s]*:\/\/.*:\d+/", $link, $match);
   echo $match[0];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parse_url()` to get url you want

```
$url = 'http://mytour.com:8080/en/admin/dashboard//tmp/Rc4Lw3';
$parse_url = parse_url($url);
echo $link = $parse_url['scheme']."://".$parse_url['host'].":".$parse_url['port'];
echo "<br>";
//You can also use default method and params
echo $link = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME)."//".parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST).":".parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @vladkras use parse_url($link)

```
$url = 'http://mytour.com:8080/en/admin/dashboard//tmp/Rc4Lw3';
$parse = parse_url($url);
echo $parse['scheme'].'://'.$parse['host'].':'.$parse['port'];
```

Output:

```
http://mytour.com:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = 'http://mytour.com:8080/en/admin/dashboard//tmp/Rc4Lw3';
 $url = parse_url($link);
echo $url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'].':'.$url['port'];
```